# If x and y are real, solve the equation $\frac{xi}{1+yi}=\frac{3x+4i}{x+3y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If x and y are real, solve the equation
>   $$\frac{xi}{1+yi}=\frac{3x+4i}{x+3y}$$

I have tried giving both sides of the equation a common denominator of $(1+yi)(x+3y)$ and then manipulating the resulting numerators, but I couldn't get anything helpful to appear. I have also tried multiplying the LHS by $\frac{1-yi}{1-yi}$, but again couldn't see how to proceed. Undrstanding how to do this is more important than knowing the answer (which is  in the back of the book: Stroud's Fundamentals of Engineering Mathematics).

I am reading the book for self study, so this is not a homework assignment, I just would really like to understand how to do this.

Comment: Hint: cross multiply, collect all terms, then solve real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Another approach: conjugate both sides of this equation to get a new equation. Now you have two equations in two variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply by the common denominator to get

$$xi(x+3y)=(3x+4i)(1+yi)$$

Write as real and imaginary parts.

$$x(x+3y)i=3x+4i+3xyi-4y$$

$$x(x+3y)i=(3x-4y)+(3xy+4)i$$

Thus the real and imaginary parts on both sides are equal. This gives:

$$x(x+3y)=3xy+4$$
$$3x-4y=0$$

I think you can solve this system of equations.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now: there is a section in the book on this and I understand what is going on now :)

Answer (score 2):

$(x^2+3xy)i = 3x+4i+3xyi-4y=(3x-4y)+(4+3xy)i$ . Now "equate" the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$xi(x+3y)=(3x+4i)(1+yi)$

$=>i(x^2+3xy)=3x-4y+i(4+3xy)$

```
Equating real and imaginary on both sides
```

$x^2+3xy=4+3xy$ and $3x-4y=0$

$=>x^2=4$ and $3x=4y$

$=>x=+or-2$

and

$3(2)=4y$or $3(-2)=4y$

$ if x=2 then y=\frac{3}{2}$

$if x=-2then y=\frac{-3}{2}$